# Delete records from multiply tables ASP Web Api

Tags: c#, sql, database, asp.net-web-api

In my Web Api application I have some tables like these, and when creating a `process` and upload files some information added to `tableLogs`:

```
tableProcess
-------------------
ProcessId    Name
1            proc1
2            proc2

tableFile
------------------------------
FileId    ProcessId    Name
1             1        file1
2             1        file2
3             1        file3
4             2        file4
5             2        file5

tableLogs
------------------
LogId    FileId    Description
1          1          log1
2          1          log2
3          2          log3
4          2          log4
5          3          log5
6          4          log6
7          5          log7
```

I need when delete a `process` delete records from all of this tables, for example if I want to delete `proc1`, files `file1`, `file2`, & `file3` should be deleted from `tableFile` and the first five logs that matched those three files should be deleted from `tableLogs`. And I didn't get to delete logs related to `tableFile`. Any suggestions how to do that?

**UPDATE**

I create a store procedure, as it was suggested by @websch01ar in his answer and now my method looks like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult DeleteLeadProcess(int id)
        {
            var procId = db.tableProcess.SingleOrDefault(p => p.ProcessId == id);

            string errMsg = null;
            using (var transaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    db.deleteProcess(id);
                    transaction.Commit();  <-- error here
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                    errMsg = e.Message;
                    return BadRequest(errMsg);
                }
            }
            return Ok("Process " + procId.ProcessName + " has been deleted successfully!");
}
```

The procedure works fine if I run it in SQL Server, but in controller I have an error "A System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was thrown: "The transaction operation cannot be performed because there are pending requests working on this transaction."

Comment: Are you able to leverage stored procedures in your environment?

Comment: @websch01ar, yes, I can use stored procedures

Comment: Alex, I would recommend that type of process.  It will simplify your web api method and place the SQL work where it belongs...on the SQL DB.  Do you need help writing that sproc?

Comment: @websch01ar, yes, it would be nice if you can help me with writing the procedure, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation is to switch to executing a stored procedure when you need to handle cascading deletes like you want.  Here is a contrived stored procedure you may use.  Please note, I am using my own sproc template and you may not need all of this

```
USE [Database]
GO

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[csp_Application_DeleteProcessRecords]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[csp_Application_DeleteProcessRecords]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[csp_Application_DeleteProcessRecords]
    @ProcessID int
AS
BEGIN

    /******************************************************************************
    **  File: csp_Application_DeleteProcessRecords.sql
    **  Name: csp_Application_DeleteProcessRecords
    **  Desc: 
    *******************************************************************************
    **  Change History
    *******************************************************************************
    **  Date:       Author:             Description:
    **  --------    --------            -------------------------------------------
    **  07-31-00    Cool Developer      Creation.
    **
    *******************************************************************************/
    BEGIN TRY

        /*
            Delete from tableLogs
        */
            Delete TL
            from [Database].dbo.tableLogs TL
            JOIN [Database].dbo.tableFile TF on TL.FileID = TF.FileID
            Where TF.ProcessID = @ProcessID;

        /*
            Delete from tableFile
        */
            Delete TF
            from [Database].dbo.tableFile TF
            Where TF.ProcessID = @ProcessID;

        /*
            Delete from Process
        */
            Delete TP
            from [Database].dbo.tableProcess TP 
            where ProcessID = @ProcessID;

            Select 1; -- true as an output?
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH

        BEGIN
            Rollback;
            DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000), @ErrorSeverity INT, @ErrorState INT;

            SELECT 
                @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
                @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
                @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();

            RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);
        END

    END CATCH;
END
Go

/*
**  Test Scripts
*/

/*
Declare @ProcessID int = (Select 'A')
exec [Database].dbo.csp_Application_DeleteProcessRecords @ProcessID 1

*/
```

Comment: I have an error when trying this code, maybe you can help?

"The data reader returned by the store data provider does not have enough columns for the query requested"
I`ll add updated controller in my question

Comment: Sorry for the delay, it looks like you got past this but you are now receiving a transaction error.  Have you tried called db.SaveChanges() just before the commit message?

Comment: I have tried that, but I still have an error "The transaction operation cannot be performed because there are pending requests working on this transaction." So I just take a piece of your procedure to remove records from tableLog and write it in C# with my old controller and it works for me. Thank you for help)